# Puppet - using hiera parameters in top scope manifests

Tags: puppet, devops

I have a site.pp file which looks like this:

```
Package {allow_virtual => false,}

stage { 'pre': before => Stage['main'] }
stage { 'post': require => Stage['main'] }

resources { 'firewall': purge => true }

node default {
  hiera_include('classes')
}
```

I’d like to be able to set the firewall purge line based on the value of a hiera parameter.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible.  You cannot rely on automated data binding but you can still use call the `hiera()` function to perform a lookup by explicit key.